# How to collect data inside Java Stream from external service?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have such Java 7 code

```
List<String> foodPreferencesStr = ... populating this list

EdamamRequestModel params = new EdamamRequestModel();
List<EdamamRecipeModel> recipesList = new ArrayList<EdamamRecipeModel>();

for(String pref : foodPreferencesStr) {
    params.setQ(pref);
    params.setFrom(fromInt);
    params.setTo(toInt);
    recipesList.addAll(edamamService.searchRecipe(params));
}
```

How to make it Java 8 with Stream API?

I tried to make it like this

```
List<EdamamRecipeModel> recipesList = foodPreferencesStr.stream()
        .map(pref -> {
            params.setQ(pref);
            params.setFrom(fromInt);
            params.setTo(toInt);

            return params;
        }).collect(...);
```

but do not understand how to call `edamamService.searchRecipe(params)` inside Stream API and add all its result to `List<EdamamRecipeModel> recipesList`

Please advice.

Comment: yes. it returns "collect
(java.util.stream.Collector<? super com.foodniche.rest.model.EdamamRequestModel,A,R>)
in Stream cannot be applied
to
(java.util.List<com.foodniche.rest.model.EdamamRecipeModel>)
 
 reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) A, R exist so that List<EdamamRecipeModel> conforms to Collector<? super EdamamRequestModel, A, R>"

Answer (score 3):

```
List<EdamamRecipeModel> recipesList = foodPreferencesStr.stream()
        .map(pref -> {
            EdamamRequestModel params = new EdamamRequestModel();

            params.setQ(pref);
            params.setFrom(fromInt);
            params.setTo(toInt);

            return params;
        })
        .map(params -> edamamService.searchRecipe(params))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Comment: The same answer I gave, but you posted it earlier, so I'm deleting mine.